# Why is Ebean not recognising a non-primitive @Transient member variable?

Tags: java, persistence, ebean, transient

I would like to exclude `items` from Ebean persistence.

Here is my bean:

```
package entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.avaje.ebean.validation.Length;
import com.avaje.ebean.validation.NotNull;

@Entity()
@Table(name="profile")
public class Profile {

    private Item[] items;

    @Transient
    public Item[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Item[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Length(max=50)
    @NotNull
    private String externalReference;

    ...
```

But I get the following stack trace:

```
[20:16:18] [Server thread/ERROR]: Was unable to use reflection to find a constructor and appropriate getters forimmutable type class [Lentity.Item;.  The errors while looking for the getter methods follow:
[20:16:18] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error with entity.Profile field:items
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to use reflection to build ImmutableMeta for class [Lentity.Item;.  Associated Errors trying to find a constructor and getter methods have been logged
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.createImmutableMeta(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:71) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.DefaultTypeManager.recursiveCreateScalarTypes(DefaultTypeManager.java:224) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:367) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:387) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:168) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:94) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createDeployBeanInfo(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1041) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentInitial(BeanDescriptorManager.java:552) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:269) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:143) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:209) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:63) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:78) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.init(JavaPlugin.java:344) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:104) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:67) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at profile.ProfilePlugin.<init>(ProfilePlugin.java:16) [crm-profile.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:52) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:328) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:294) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:723) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:548) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:625) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1299) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1159) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:37) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:9) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:690) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:360) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:646) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:550) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.7.0_45]
[20:16:18] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error in deployment
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error with [entity.Profile] I believe it is not enhanced but it's superClass [class java.lang.Object] is? (You are not allowed to mix enhancement in a single inheritance hierarchy)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setBeanReflect(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1393) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1161) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1077) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:584) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:271) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:143) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:209) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:63) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:78) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.init(JavaPlugin.java:344) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:104) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:67) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at profile.ProfilePlugin.<init>(ProfilePlugin.java:16) [crm-profile.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:52) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:129) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:328) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:294) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:723) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:548) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:625) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1299) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1159) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:37) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:9) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_45]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:690) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:360) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:646) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:550) [craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field [items] not found in [entity.Profile$$EntityBean$crm-profile][id, externalReference, playerId, location, clan, playerClass, visible, deleted, health, level, pvpKills, pvpDeaths, mobKills, mobDeaths, onlineDuration, durationSinceLastDeath, lastUpdated, lastDeathDurationCheck]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.reflect.EnhanceBeanReflect.getFieldIndex(EnhanceBeanReflect.java:139) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.reflect.EnhanceBeanReflect.getGetter(EnhanceBeanReflect.java:143) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setBeanReflect(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1377) ~[craftbukkit-1.10.2.jar:git-Bukkit-0ebb9c7]
        ... 40 more
```

Could someone please tell me how to correctly declare the member variable `items` as `@Transient` so that it is excluded from persistence?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, you need to apply the  `@Transient` annotation to the field `items` (not on `getItems()`) as shown below:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="profile")
public class Profile {

  @Id
  private int id;

  @Transient
  private Item[] items;

  public Item[] getItems() {
    return items;
  }

   ...
}
```

**P.S.:** When you have `@Transient` fields, make sure that you are placing JPA annotations consistently either on the getter methods or on the fields, not distributing them on both places. In your current code, other JPA annotations (like `@Id`) have been marked for fields except `@Transient`.

It does the trick however I could not find anything in JPA spec or on Hibernate on this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution for me. Do you know what version of Ebean you were using? I found this bug reported at Ebean and apparently fixed in version 4.0.1: https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/11. It is unclear, also, what version of Ebean Minecraft craftbukkit 1.10.2 uses (I'm guessing an older version..).

Comment: I could not find anything related to Transient on the issue link you shared

Comment: Oh Sorry, I fixed the link: https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in versions of EBean prior to 4.0.1. The work around is to:

> 1. Change the property to a List or Set rather than array.
> 2. Mark the field with "transient" as well if possible, i.e. if you don't need to use Java serialization on the field.

As stated in this relevant [bug report](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/111).